# SQL Error Exception in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to show the exception that is being thrown because of SQL store procedure failure.I am getting the response in ajax but that is to with requst.responseText but I dont want to access the whole responseText.I need only the title of this responseText

My Controller is as Follows:

```
public ActionResult ReOrderSegment(string DocumentIDs, long DossierIDForReOrder) 
        {
            try
            {
                var TrimmedString = DocumentIDs.TrimEnd('#');

                var DocumentIDsWithInteger = Convert.ToInt64(DocumentIDs.Split('#').FirstOrDefault());

                long SelectedCompany = db.Documents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == DocumentIDsWithInteger).CompanyID;

                var Message = db.PerformAutomatedSorting(SelectedCompany, DossierIDForReOrder, TrimmedString);

                return Json(Message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 500;
                Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
                return Json(new { errorMessage = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            return Json(0);
        }
```

and JS:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: rootUrl("Dossier/ReOrderSegment"),
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { DocumentIDs: DocumentIDs, DossierIDForReOrder: DossierIDForReOrder },
                    traditional: true,
                    success: function (rest)
                    {
                        alert(rest);

                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error)
                    {
                        //var all = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                        alert(request.responseText);
                    }   
                });
            });
```

here i am attaching the images 
[image]

here i want to show only "Please select only Air Product that are UnInvoiced" in alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code in your error block:

```
var newTitle = $(request.responseText).filter('title').text(); // or try find('title').text();
```

The variable newTitle above should show you the title.

But Ideally you should try creating a small class for ErrorDetails with properties like a string Message, or a List Messages to save all your validation messages and return to the client like this in your catch block in controller:

```
ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails();
errorDetails.Message = "Please select only Air Product that are UnInvoiced";
return Json(errorDetails, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And In jquery code, read the error details like this:

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var obj = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText); //can also use xhr.responseJSON directly instead of parsing it.
  alert(obj.Message);
  //use this obj to to read message or list of messages by for loop.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I am doing it which you may find helpful.

In base controller:

```
 protected virtual JsonResult JsonError(Exception error, string message = null, int statusCode = 500)
        {
            JsonNetResult res = new JsonNetResult();
            res.ContentType = "application/json";
            res.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            res.Data = new JsonErrorModel(){ error = error, message = message };

            if (error != null)
                Log.Error(message, error);
            else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
                Log.Error(message);

            int newStatus = statusCode;
            if (error != null)
            {
                if (error is ArgumentException || error is ArgumentNullException || error is AbsenceSoftException)
                    newStatus = 400;
                var aggErr = error as AbsenceSoftAggregateException;
                if (aggErr != null)
                {
                    newStatus = 400;
                    message = message ?? string.Join("; ", aggErr.Messages);
                }
            }

            if (Response != null)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = newStatus;
                Response.StatusDescription = message ?? (error == null ? "An error has ocurred" : error.Message);
            }

            return res;
        }
```

in HomeController:basecontroller

```
 public JsonResult TestCase(Model model)
        {
            try
            {
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return JsonError(ex);
            }
        }
```

However, I am thinking to re-factor it, and to implement it as a reusable exception handling  attribute or possibly managing the error handling code logic in global.asax.cs application_error method.